# Typescript error - Cannot use import statement outside a module , while importing MongoServerError

Tags: typescript, mongodb, es6-modules, npm-package

tsconfig File for my project

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/types/*"]
    },
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

    "strict": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Code generating error -

`import { MongoServerError } from './../node_modules/mongodb/src/error';`

Usage inside file-

```
  if (error instanceof MongoServerError) {
        console.log(`Database error ${error.name} ${error.message}`)
        console.error(error); 
   }
```

Error -

```
/Users/akshaydohroo/Documents/WebDev/portfolio-backend/node_modules/mongodb/src/error.ts:1
import type { Document } from './bson';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:73:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1166:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1210:27)
    at Module._compile (/Users/akshaydohroo/Documents/WebDev/portfolio-backend/node_modules/source-map-support/source-map-support.js:568:25)
    at Module.m._compile (/private/var/folders/5z/1xf4s3bj7rv208l3hjvtt9th0000gn/T/ts-node-dev-hook-4565640683260823.js:69:33)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1300:10)
    at require.extensions..jsx.require.extensions..js (/private/var/folders/5z/1xf4s3bj7rv208l3hjvtt9th0000gn/T/ts-node-dev-hook-4565640683260823.js:114:20)
    at require.extensions.<computed> (/private/var/folders/5z/1xf4s3bj7rv208l3hjvtt9th0000gn/T/ts-node-dev-hook-4565640683260823.js:71:20)
    at Object.nodeDevHook [as .ts] (/Users/akshaydohroo/Documents/WebDev/portfolio-backend/node_modules/ts-node-dev/lib/hook.js:63:13)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1103:32)
[ERROR] 21:04:41 SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

what is the cause of this error and how to debug it? any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to import something from other library, other file or other folder?

Comment: @LucasA I am trying to import MongoServerError class from the MongoDB npm package to type-check errors more accurately.